# SVN commit does not seem to work

Tags: svn, commit

I do svn commit from the directory I want to commit, it looks like it accepts the command, but when I checked out the same directory it gave me the previous copy - none of the updates were reflected.

Comment: More info please? Give us the steps you did, and what you get. Otherwise, it'll be closed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to verify commit is to look `svn log` after it. Your commited changeset should be listed on top of the log. Otherwise something went wrong or there was nothing to commit.